Update to the right sidebar header
We have made an update to the right sidebar design. This update has made the right sidebar as well as all right sidebar widgets across the network to be more consistent, uniform and have easier readability. These changes are already live on Stack Overflow on the homepage, where these updates have already been released. This change will impact the header of the widget specifically by removing the border and background color, and adjusting the spacing/sizing. Colors will be otherwise unaffected.  You can see the technical details of the sidebar widget changes on Stacks.



Please let us know if you have any questions or notice any bugs. We will be keeping an eye on this post for feedback till December 23rd, 2024

Hey Charlotte, it's great that y'all are working on usability! Now I'm curious what's exactly new. Can you share a side-by-side comparison of the old and new design with the same content in both designs? I tried comparing your screenshot to the actual sidebar I see, but as the content is different, it's hard to spot the changes.

Even if the change isn't live yet, I do appreciate the advance notice. Please consider publishing these posts for future design changes in advance of them rolling out to production. Without advance notice, such changes do come across as very jarring and having such notice greatly reduces that for me.

What is that recent searches bit... how would it even work given the so jobs tool is a separate entity

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/432470/discussions-guideline-on-the-sidebar-is-mingled

@Sonic thanks, but it's still confusing as the design on SO homepage is still different than the one in the screenshot here, and it does match now (it didn't before) only in the /Questions page. And overall, I really don't see how this is better, but that's already just me aka own personal taste.

@KevinB the images in the post are from Stacks documentation, these are just examples using placeholder content and are not real. The example content was likely (taking a best guess here) referencing something from the old legacy job board and we never bothered to change the placeholder copy in Stacks.

Why do we need <div class="js-sidebar-zone" style="min-height: 300px;"> on the SO homepage? The minimum height results in an empty space between widgets. I actually appreciate the class/div as I can use it for my userscript: https://stackapps.com/questions/10634/hide-the-newly-introduced-homepage-widgets/10635#10635 but you should get rid of the minimum height probably. It seems to work as intended on other sites without the style.

Why hasn't the SO Home page received this update? it still has no background and space between blog and featured.

Another bug: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/432480/reviews-completed-today-looks-wrong-in-on-staging-ground-questions

@KevinB see this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/432470/discussions-guideline-on-the-sidebar-is-mingled/432478?noredirect=1#comment1013512_432478
